# rsync copying existing files with --ignore-existing flag

Tags: linux, rsync

I'm trying to sync two dirs on two USB drives via rsync. Running on MacOS Monterey. Using command

`rsync -ravh --ignore-existing --progress --dry-run /Volumes/Drive-01/mystuff /Volumes/Drive-02/mystuff/`

Sync will copy every file from source to destination, despite the fact that they are identical. Visually inspected, they are the same. Used `diff` on several files, and it confirmed they were the same as well. Used `ls -le` and owner, perms, and mtime are identical on both drives. I also ran rsync with other options, like `rsync -auvh` with same results.

What would rsync see as a difference (triggering copy) that I cannot see using above methods..?

Comment: The `-a` option provides `-rlptgoD (no -A,-X,-U,-N,-H)`  Generally you want `-auv` to sync only "newer" (`-u` `--update`) files to the server.  For dry-run you can use `-n` for a total of `rsync -uavn src dest` which only transfers non-existing or newer files to the `dest` in a dry-run.

Comment: Your other issue is you are creating `.../mystuff/mystuff` in the `dest` location. You only want `rsync -ravh --ignore-existing --progress --dry-run /Volumes/Drive-01/mystuff /Volumes/Drive-02` as the command to copy `mystuff` below `/Volumes/Drive-02`

Comment: Your question is not "Programming" related, it is more appropriate for the StackExchange sites [Super User](http://superuser.com/) (though questions of this type do appear from time to time on SO, it's generally in the context of a larger script)

Comment: I have the same problem and it seems to be the -r that causes it because when the source and dest are paths to a file it does detect it already exists and skips